# How to transfer localhost to open server

Tags: apache, tomcat, mahout

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://ssc.io/a-recommendation-webservice-in-10-minutes/). To train the Mahout engine they mention to use the command:

```
http://localhost:8080/kornakapi/train?recommender=itembased
```

This works. However I want to open up the server so that I can run this remotely. The code is running on a server at a specified IP address, let's call it 999.999.9.999. When I try

```
http://999.999.9.999/kornakapi/train?recommender=itembased
```

I get a 404 error. Obviously the server isn't setup to accept incoming connections (though phpMyAdmin works remotely). How can I setup the server to allow an external connection in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your gateway to accept incoming requests. Access your modem and search for a setting that allows one computer on your LAN to open up all its ports.  You have to enter in the computer's local IP